# Android MapView getMap() returns null

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

`MapView`'s `getMap()` method can return null.  I know this is an intended behavior by Google.

Can someone provide a **definitive** description as to when and under which circumstances the `getMap()` method returns null?

I know that if Google Services are unavailable on the given device, `getMap()` will return null.  This eventuality is relatively well documented.  I'm more concerned with the vague other case where even when Google Services are installed on a device, `getMap()` can still return null.

My assumption up to this point is that there is some initialization of the underlying maps system, during which time your code might execute and get a null map.

Am I correct in my assumption?

Is there any particular place in the Activity or Fragment lifecycle where we can definitively get a non-null `GoogleMap` (if we assume Google Services IS installed)?

My goal in asking this question is to prevent a litany of `if(mapView.getMap() != null)` checks littered throughout my code.  In addition, this question seems to still come up on a regular basis here on StackOverflow and I'd like to see if we can flesh out the truth behind what exactly is going on with `MapView` and `getMap()`

Comment: You should try using mapfragment instead of mapview. The mapfragment can handle its lifecycle and prevents the null value being returned.

Comment: Rani, I almost always find myself needing a map that I can manipulate within a fragment.  Using a MapFragment would then require embedded fragments which have documented issues.  This question is for those of us in situations that require a MapView.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Scenarios handled by Google**
If the google play apk is not installed you will get a null.  But its somehow built in to download it from the playstore.  But the playstore may not be installed so you get a null map.  If the internet isn't available and the playstore is installed but google play services is not you get a null because google play services can't be installed.  But coding for these senarios is done for you.

**Scenarios handled by your code.**
This is what you have to code for.  If you deviate from the pattern outlined in the map samples you will get a null map. Every sample does it the same way.  This is so if the first call in onCreate fails there is still a second chance to get the map in onResume.  Your solution is to call `getMap()` only in one place and save the map object that is returned.  Follow the basic pattern that the map samples use.  In the `onCreate` and `onResume` methods you call `setupmapifneeded` which inturn calls `setupmap` when the map object is not null.

Here's the first map sample.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.gosylvester.testapp;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

/**
 * This shows how to create a simple activity with a map and a marker on the map.
 * <p>
 * Notice how we deal with the possibility that the Google Play services APK is not
 * installed/enabled/updated on a user's device.
 */
public class BasicMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available.
     */
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not have been
     * completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be stopped or
     * paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this method in
     * {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Comment: to clarify, if a map will *every* be available, then you will get a reference in either onCreate or onResume?  And if both of those references are null, then a map will never become available?  Also, do you happen to know what would cause a map to be unavailable in onCreate but later become available in onResume?

Comment: Yes If both fail to get a map then the map will be unavailable.  In Theory this will never happen.  Once you get the map working it is very stable.  IDK you might get a map in OnResume if the app is started immediately after the phone is booted.

Answer (score 7):

Google has a more convenient way to get the map using the following method, because it might depend from a device to device to get the map ready!
Use the following method to get the map when it is ready.

```
myMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback) {
     @Override
     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
         myMap = googleMap;
     }
});
```

Comment: What event do you call this from?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference, only that the mapFragment is not null and then the block will be called whenever the map is ready

Answer (score 0):

I have an Android Tab3 Running Android 4.2.2
All I had to do is update google maps and it did the trick.