# Getting Google MapView V2 to work

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

Has anyone been able to get Google MapView V2 to work?  I trolled through StackOverflow (including this question: [Android MapView getMap() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471766/android-mapview-getmap-returns-null)) and everyone seems to be unable to use MapView and end up having to use the Fragment.

Having the following google_map_view.xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I attempt to instantiate the map in this fashion:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );           
googleMapView = (View) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.google_map_view, null);
MapView mapView = (MapView)googleMapView.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
GoogleMap googleMap = mapView.getMap();
```

googleMap will be null.

Google Play Services is correctly associated with the app and I have the correct keys in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try calling `onCreate()` on the `MapView` before trying to retrieve the `GoogleMap`, and see if that helps. You might also try a `MapFragment` temporarily -- even if you do not intend to use a `MapFragment` long-term, it might be useful to suss out any configuration problems with the rest of your app with respect to Maps V2.

Comment: mapView.getMap() a little further down the line. Like in onActivityStarted()

Comment: I tried both approaches with no joy.  I am going to have to do the MapFragment approach even through it involves a quite a bit of rework.  It is very irritating that Google puts this mechanism out there but it does not work in what seems the most simplistic cases. Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning Google Maps API V2 too, last week, got map done by this:

In my activity layout, where I want map to appear I just wrote:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/PickDestMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

That can be placed inside of LinearLayout or any other layout you wish.

In Activity Java file:

then in onCreate:

```
//Get fragment from activity (which was created in above layout file)
SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.PickDestMap);

GoogleMap wMap = smf.getMap();
```

Now using wMap you can configure, edit, modify map as you wish. 
Assuming your keys are set properly, play services properly imported, it should work straight away.

For test purposes I just removed all code in my Activity.java and it worked fine.

Comment: You did not read my post, for a number of reasons I am choosing not to use Fragment.  I have used the Fragment approach successfully in other apps but that approach is not appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Google now made a more convenient way to get the map using the following method

```
myMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback) {
     @Override
     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
         myMap = googleMap;
     }
});
```