# MapFragment or MapView getMap() returns null on Lollipop

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, android-5.0-lollipop

I've been using Google Maps API v2 for a long time on Android 4.x versions without a problem. Now I installed latest Lollipop build on my Nexus devices (5 and 7) trying to materialize the app.

I'd like to point out that everything is ok on KitKiat and the problem I'm describing is poping up only on Lollipop.

In my XML source code I'm using MapFragment (Google Play Services library version 6.1.11).

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

In Java code I'm overriding OnPause() method to reach map:

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

At this line it throws NullPointerException. In debugger app is able to find fragment, however it's not able to return GoogleMap. I've also tried to use MapView. It also throws null.
The weirdest thing for me is that map loads without a problem on app itself but in code I cant reach it to work with it.

Comment: I would check if that's a timing issue (Fragment is not yet created). Try to get the Fragment after some delay for experiment.

Comment: This is answered in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/22624155/706833

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @DoctororDrive - Tried 3s loop without a success.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem but this is what worked for me:

Replace this...

`GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

with this...

`GoogleMap map = getMapFragment().getMap();`

then slip this bad boy in and give it a whirl...

```
private MapFragment getMapFragment() {
    FragmentManager fm = null;

    Log.d(TAG, "sdk: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    Log.d(TAG, "release: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Log.d(TAG, "using getFragmentManager");
        fm = getFragmentManager();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "using getChildFragmentManager");
        fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    }

    return (MapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
}
```

Comment: Is this a known issue on Lollipop?

Comment: @Rhisiart thanks for your answer .i want to know one more thing .after using this code ..how we will handle on backstack with this fragment in navigation drawer ...bcz after using this code onbackstack is not working with this fragment.

Comment: @DeepSingh without more detail, all I can tell you is that my fragment extends com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment and is hosted within an android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost along with 2 other android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec's in an android.app.Activity targeting android:targetSdkVersion="22. 

You can see it in action within this app (select either 'Find nature events' or 'Find events' from the navigation drawer) - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wildlifetrusts.naturefinder

Comment: I wish I could +1 multiple times on this answer

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution but it says getChildFragmentManager is undefined. Im inside an Activity. Someone hlp me please?

Comment: Dude, you saved my time. Thanks alot

Answer (score 13):

Google now made a more convenient way to get the map using the following method

```
    myMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback) {
         @Override
         public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
             myMap = googleMap;
         }
    });
```

Comment: This was the correct answer in my case.  The accepted answer seems to assume that the MapFragment is null, which is not the case according to the question (in the question the MapFragment is not null, but the returned value of getMap() is null).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this might be an issue with a targetSdkVersion of 21:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1947

However, switching to getChildFragmentManager() worked for me:

[findFragmentById for SupportMapFragment returns null in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597161/findfragmentbyid-for-supportmapfragment-returns-null-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29) to check why its returning null? null has many reasons on getmap, try using this to check why its giving null

Comment: Yes, I did. Finally I solved my problem by reimplementing MapView. MapFragment does not seem to work at all.

Comment: @mroczis Can u just describe me how did u fix it?

Comment: I used MapView after all, set up it's lifecycle (calling mMapView.onCreate() on onCreate() method of activity, mMapView.onPause() on activity's onPause() etc.) and it did work.
MapFragment does seem to not attach to FragmentManager on Lollipop.