# Google Maps - Android App not load - null object reference

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am currently trying to develop an Android app with google Maps integration. At the moment I have difficulties to find the error, because the code is from the google site itself, except that it is a SupportMapFragment. If you know an actual tutorial with SupportMapFragment would also be great. Actual, because I think `.getMap()` is depreciated. If I should post the whole code, let me know (I am new in stackoverflow)

If try to use this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

where a function is:

```
    @Override
     public void onResume() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

The error is: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference`

The Fragment xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Map fragment is acting up on Lollipop you may need this instead.

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
        .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
} else {
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
        .getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
}
supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: This Code helped, but the App still crashes. With this Error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ey.o()' on a null object reference`

Comment: this is the exact error I am currently getting - " 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ey.o()' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you need to use the `Fragment`'s `SupportFragmentManager`
See the answer to this [findFragmentById for SupportMapFragment returns null in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597161/findfragmentbyid-for-supportmapfragment-returns-null-in-android-studio)