# Google API is returning null with signed release apk (debug apk is working fine)

Tags: android, google-api

Google API is returning null when 'm using the signed apk.Many links pointed towards the SHA1 finger print. I have supplied the SHA1 at the google account as well, but still facing the same problem. Can anyone please guide towards the solution? (Problem is only with signed release apk,it is working fine with debug apk)
Thanks

Comment: its a bug on 5.0 and up based on this https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1947 use SupportMapFragment insted, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597161/findfragmentbyid-for-supportmapfragment-returns-null-in-android-studio

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the map. I am getting null when trying to login with google API. (Problem is only with signed apk)

Comment: did you enable Google Maps Android API not Google Maps API on google console console.developers.google.com

Comment: Yes, It is enabled ...... and the solution that i found is that the SHA1 was causing problem.  Now, it is working fine . Thanks for your kind suggestions :)

Comment: did you  put Same release SHA1 in to firebase consol?