# MapFragment causing NullPointerException at getMapAsync(this) method

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, supportmapfragment, mapactivity

I have implemented an activity which adds `MapFragment` at run time. The `MapFragment` xml has static `fragment` and I'm trying to get add at run time. Also I found there are some issues in Lollipop adding the map fragment at runtime. Kindly check [Issue raised](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1947#c3) and [temporary solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597161/findfragmentbyid-for-supportmapfragment-returns-null-in-android-studio)

I have also given my codes below,

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".fragment.MapsFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="appCreators.bloodfinder.activity.MapsActivity"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    layout="@layout/template_custom_spinner"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**MapsFragment.java**

Implements `onMapReadyCallback`

```
public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback
```

In `onResume` callback

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
}
```

this always return me null and I have also tried,

```
((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
```

this also return `NullPointerException`

**MapsActivity.java**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, MapsFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

I add this at `onCreate` method of Activity callback.

I'm not able to figure out why I'm still getting `NullPointerException`!

Some times I get `Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fl.o()' on a null object reference`

Help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE:** Still not fixed I'm getting the following error. I looked into logs but no clue why this is happening.

```
Unable to resume activity {MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fl.o()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: put `((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);`  line in your `onCreateView()`

Comment: And remove `tools:context="appCreators.bloodfinder.activity.MapsActivity"` from `fragment_map.xml`

Comment: I tried but no luck I'm getting `Unable to resume activity {MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fl.o()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Any solution yet? I am stuck with this one for 2 days now.

Comment: I just solved it. Have a look at my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally solved this issue for myself by observing the given answers in SO. I compared my code and the code in the answers. It seems to me that there is some confusion about this API and Google's implementation is very broad. I got this exception thrown repeatedly:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fl.o()' on a null object reference
```

I still have no idea whats wrong with some of these implementations in SO questions that are getting the same exception, but this worked for me and it might work for someone else.

These are the the things you need to check:

1. Make sure you have both of these (I had only the api key meta-data)

   ```
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   ```
2. You have a fragment in xml like this with the class attribute being correct as below

   ```
      <fragment
       android:id="@+id/google_map_fragment"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   ```

In my case the map fragment is a child, inside another fragment.

**This parent fragment apparently should not be a MapFragment or a SupportMapFragment. After changing it from SupportMapFragment to Fragment the map showed perfectly fine.**

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {
```

I left everything else as it was before but instead of getting the map in onCreateView I got it in onViewCreated like this:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rewards_google_map_area);
    if (mapFragment != null) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager != null && mapFragment.getMap() != null) {
            googleMap=mapFragment.getMap();
            //after this you do whatever you want with the map
        }
    }

}
```

I changed nothing else and I did not mess with the rootView or parentView. As you would see in the the answer from @Konstantin Loginov

Try it out and let me know.

Comment: It looks promising. I'll try and let you know

Comment: Worked link charm! The mistake which I did is extending `SupportMapFragment` instead of `Fragment`. Changing to `Fragment` worked. Other scenario's were perfect in my case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I use raw `MapView` statically in a Fragment's xml. The problem was that I had to move the call forwarding `mMapView.onCreate(...)` to `onViewCreated(...)` because in `onCreate()` `mMapView` is not yet inflated. If you don't use `MapView` then you should double-check in which  moment you call `getMap()`. I must be after the internal MapView is inflated.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with similar issue a while ago.
The key was to `getMap()` in a proper moment, in `onViewCreated()` of the `Fragment`:

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

    private SupportMapFragment locationMap;
    private View rootView;

    protected View getFragmentView() {
        View view = getView();
        if (view == null) {
            view = rootView;
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = getFragmentView();
        if (rootView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(rootView);
            }
        }

        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup_specify_location, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException ex) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Inflate Exception in onCreateView; Caused by map fragment", ex);
        }
        ......
        return getFragmentView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        locationMap = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.locationMap);
        if (locationMap != null) {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (locationManager != null && locationMap.getMap() != null) {
                locationMap.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the XML for it looks like yours:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/locationMap"
        android:layout_above="@+id/locationLabelTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, in `onViewCreated()` you can notify `Activity`, that your map-fragment is ready to use.

I hope, it helps

Comment: I'll check this and let you know!

Comment: Hey I tried, But I'm getting this error `Unable to resume activity {MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fl.o()' on a null object reference`. I think there is something else which is causing this problem! And it's not giving me the exact line or the cause of the problem. I googled enough but ended up nothing!

Comment: Tried this. Same issue. That exception is still there.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2019**

If you're still having this problems, try this :

Don't extend SupportMapFrangemt !

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private SupportMapFragment fragment;
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_with_map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you use mapView just ensure that you called `mapView.onCreate()` before `mapView.getMapAsync()`. If you are using fragment and view still not initialized you are also able to call `mapView.onCreate()` in `onViewCreated()` method.