# getMapAsync() in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio, supportmapfragment

I having trouble implementing Google Map in Fragment.

This is my the part of my fragment class:

```
public class FragmentStoreFinderMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private int i;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
              R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
```

I am getting an error in getMapAsync(this). I tells Incompatible type.

it says:

required: com.google.android.gms.map.GoogleMap

found: void

BTW here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In your XML layout you should do like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

inside your fragment implement this

```
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
```

override **onCreateView** if there is no **onCreateView** just like the code below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
}
```

override **onViewCreated()** inside that 
**onViewCreated()** put this

```
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.onResume();
mapView.getMapAsync(this);//when you already implement OnMapReadyCallback in your fragment
```

when you already implement **OnMapReadyCallback** in your fragment put this/code like this

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
}
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: You should override onCreateView and inflate your layout like this.


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    }

Comment: Did you override the onViewCreated in your fragment ?

Comment: why do you need to invoke onCreate(savedInstanceState); and onResume(); ?

Comment: Why are you calling `mapView.onResume();` in `onViewCreated()`? Why not in `onResume()`?

Comment: I am unable to implement onMapReadyCallBack ..it shows unable to resolve

Answer (score 3):

After a few overheats in my head, thanks to this post and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732804/3925554, I would say that currently there are two ways of adding a MapFragment to your app:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

By this way, you have to use a standard fragment and implement this inside. Actually you are inserting a fragment into another:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

The other way would be extending the real SupportMapFragment and implement it in this manner without the need of an xml:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getMapAsync(this);
}
```

And they work without having to set a layout in `onCreateView` neither call `mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and `mapView.onResume();` manually inside `onViewCreated()`, what is not recommended anyway.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your onViewCreated method worked for me. The important part here is to use the Child Fragment-Manager, not the Parent Fragment-Manager

Comment: But what I said is that I recommend the second case. If your fragment extends `SupportMapFragment` you don't need a `FragmentManager`  and you don't have to inflate a fragment inside another using a layout.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
 getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flMap, mMapFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
 mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning this error because `getMapAsync()` does not return anything. If you look at the documentation for this function:

> public void getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)
>
> Sets a callback object which will be triggered when the GoogleMap
>   instance is ready to be used.
>
> Note that:
>
> This method must be called from the main thread. The callback will be
>   executed in the main thread. In the case where Google Play services is
>   not installed on the user's device, the callback will not be triggered
>   until the user installs it. In the rare case where the GoogleMap is
>   destroyed immediately after creation, the callback is not triggered.
>   The GoogleMap object provided by the callback is non-null.

OnMapReadyCallback is an interface that needs implemented and passed to through this function. Nothing is currently assigned to your `googleMap` variable you should instead set its value in this block of code which `implements OnMapReadyCallback`

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;


    }
```

This code should be in your Fragment somewhere. Since your Fragment already implements this interface you do pass it in as `this`.

Comment: I already have the onMapReady on my class. thanks for the answer btw,