# What is the function that can be used instead of "this" in "Fragment"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm implementing the autocomplete suggestion code in Google map place api.
We are using `OnMapReadyCallback` as an implement.

The `MapView.getMapAsync(this)` function was originally used in `onCreateView`. But now I'm going to use it in `setupAutoCompleteFragment`. However, in `MapView.getMapAsync(this)`, it is not compiled due to `this`. What can be used?

```
public class googlemaptab extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    MapView mapview;
    Button kakaobutton;
    public static googlemaptab newInstance(){
        return new googlemaptab();
    }
    public googlemaptab() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_googlemaptab, container, false);
        kakaobutton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.kakaobutton);

        mapview = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.google_map_view);
        setupAutoCompleteFragment();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        kakaobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //클릭하면 카카오maptab으로 이동하겠다.
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment(kakaomaptab.newInstance());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapview.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapview.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(mapview != null)
        {
            mapview.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng SEOUL = new LatLng(37.56, 126.97);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(SEOUL);
        markerOptions.title("서울");
        markerOptions.snippet("수도");
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(SEOUL));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
    }

    private void setupAutoCompleteFragment() {

        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getActivity().
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                mapview.getMapAsync(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.e("Error", status.getStatusMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What can be used instead of "this" in mapview.getMapAsync(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it better this way

```
private void setupAutoCompleteFragment(OnMapReadyCallback instance) {

        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getActivity().
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                mapview.getMapAsync(instance);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.e("Error", status.getStatusMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

And don't forget to update your `onCreateView` with the new function signature as the following:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_googlemaptab, container, false);
        kakaobutton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.kakaobutton);

        mapview = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.google_map_view);
        setupAutoCompleteFragment(this);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Classname.this` in this case.

For example: if your fragment name is `HomeFragment` then,

```
HomeFragment.this
```

If this still doesn't work then you can override `onViewCreated()` function and call `mapView.getMapAsync(this)` inside `onViewCreated()`

If needed check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496493/getmapasync-in-fragment)

Comment: That's a code smell! the `HomeFragment` can easily be leaked this way.

Comment: If it leaks the `HomeFragment` then probably overriding `onViewCreated `method and writing the code there can be done.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with mapview.getMapAsync(getActivity()); instead of mapview.getMapAsync(this);