# findFragmentById(R.id.map) returns null in Android L

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-5.0-lollipop, android-maps-v2

While testing a location based app in Android 4.4 we were able to properly see and use map via Android maps v2

Since the time I upgraded to Android L it is not able to fetch MapFragment with the following code:

1. In MainActivity there's a FrameLayout in which I load ShowMapFragment.
2. In ShowMapFragment there is a MapFragment to  display map.
3. Inside 'OnCreateView()' method
   `mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   map = mapFragment.getMap();`

mapFragment is coming as null. Any help on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it. Posting this if anyone else faces the same issue. Basically we have to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` because the MapFragment is inside another fragemnt. See the answer by Rhisiart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592889/mapfragment-or-mapview-getmap-returns-null-on-lollipop#answer-27681586).