# getMap() is null in SupportMapFragment in google map in android fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I am using google map in a fragment and getting null when calling getMap(), this is my code:

In my MapViewFragment

```
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
```

I am getting null at this line, in onCreate() method...

```
        mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

In fragment_map_view file

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597161/findfragmentbyid-for-supportmapfragment-returns-null-in-android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MapView getMap() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471766/android-mapview-getmap-returns-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason for it, I think I should post for future readers......

Actually as I GoogleMap was called in a fragment so, in the line..

```
mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager(), getSupportFragmentManager() should be used in fragments.
```

Corrected one-

```
mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: You should accept one of the above given answers because it contains same solution as you solved :).

Comment: you are right they solved but shortest solution for that time was above.

Answer (score 2):

The `getMap` method is deprecated. You should use `getMapAsync`:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

     @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        // Do something with your map
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

did you add the permissions and google API key ?

here is my code from project call this function in OnCreate()

```
private void CheckGoogleMap()
    {

        try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                        findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

in XML file

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
```

in Manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <permission         android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

before closing of application TAG in Manifest file add this

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR API KEY" />
```

in Gradle add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```